# rules to apply monte carlo simulation of p-values for chi square test

Tags: montecarlo, chi-squared

I'm sorry if it is not the right place, but i did not find the answer elsewhere. I'd like to know if I understood well the use of monte carlo simulation for the use of chisq.test().

I have a qualitative variable which has 128 levels/classes. My sample size is 26 (I was not able to sample more "individuals"). So obviously, I will have some levels with 0 "individuals". But the fact is that I have only a very small number of classes represented out of the 127 possible. As it is said (I do not completely understand the reason for that) that to apply chi square test we should have at least 5 individuals in each level, I thought I had to use the simulate.p.value option (in R) to use monte carlo simulation to estimate the distribution and compute a p-value. Without Montecarlo simulation, R give me a p-value < 1e-16. With Monte-Carlo simulation, it gives me a p-value at 4e-5.

I tried to compute the p-value with a vector of 26 ones and 101 zeros, and with Monte-Carlo simulation, I get a p-value at 1.

is it OK to state that, even if my sample size is small in comparison to the number of possible classes, the observed distribution is such that it is very unlikely that all possible classes exists at the same probability (1/127) in the real population ?

Thanks for your help

Julien